# How to automatically generate column names in SSIS' Connection Manager

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, fixed-width, fixed-length-record

I have a (fixed length) flat text file that contains 500 columns. Obviously, I'm not going to sit here and type them up, I have the column names in Excel as well. So I tried to keep the column names and then remove all the rows - then I exported the result into a CSV comma delimited file. So then I got the right column names:

[image]

Seemingly the problem was resolved. But then I went back to change the input type from Delimited file to fixed-length file... and it removed all columns...

Does anyone have a solution for this? I have all 500 column names in Excel, but I don't want to "add a column" one  by one and copy/paste each field. That's just many hours of work. Thank you so much! 
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using PowerShell?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work... I am unable to find the file (any specific files) that is created once I amend or modify the connection manager. Also, even if I do, are you suggesting that I modify the file content? I presume it has a lot of binary components in it.

Comment: You can talk SSIS from PowerShell - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2011/11/17/ssis-and-powershell-in-sql-server-2012.aspx so you should be able to read your CSV file in PowerShell and then emit whatever SSIS operations you need from that.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work for me. Still waiting on others to come forward with different solutions

Comment: You should update your post to reflect your efforts. What was "it" that you tried?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is just one way to do this: third-party addins. I looked and went through hundreds of pages/forums. Basically this is just another pitfall for SSIS that leaves much to desire for.